# VBA IF AND based on two columns

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am totally new in macro's so I would like to know where did I make mistakes in my code.

I just want a simple IF - AND based on 2 different columns and the result should be in the third column

My code is:

```
   Sub FTL_Customer3()

   Lastrow = Sheets("Raw data").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 1 To Lastrow

   If Sheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 5) = "Postponed to next month" And Sheets("Raw 
   data").Cells(i, 13) = "ATP Ship date after EOM" Then
   Cells(i, 7).Value = "OK"
   
   End If
   Next I
   End Sub
```

Comment: We need more details.  What is you code doing that is incorrect?  Does it error?  If so, on which line?

Comment: I am getting run-time error: 13 on this line:

If Sheets("Raw data").Cells(i, 5) = "Postponed to next month" And Sheets("Raw 
   data").Cells(i, 13) = "ATP Ship date after EOM" Then

Comment: Then most likely you have errors in column E or column M  You cannot equate an error to a string

Comment: Meanwhile, the result is appearing in the excel file but I am still getting an error message so the macro stops everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the cells you will be testing do not contain an error:

```
Sub FTL_Customer3()
    With Worksheets("Raw data")
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Not IsError(.Cells(i, 5)) And Not IsError(.Cells(i, 13)) Then
                If .Cells(i, 5) = "Postponed to next month" And _
                    .Cells(i, 13) = "ATP Ship date after EOM" Then
                    .Cells(i, 7).Value = "OK"
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: THank you  it is working perfectly! You were right! I had some errors in the columns. Many thanks again!